# Disable / Not implemented yet of endpoints in Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm using Swagger as documentation of my API so that others can use this to build other services reliant on this. I would like to still show the endpoints that are not implemented yet on the UI so that the others can see the expected format of in and outputs, however I would also like to indicate that they are not available yet. Is there some way to disable the `try it out` feature for example?

Comment: Do you use Swagger UI [from the repo](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/), or as provided part of some library/framework (e.g. Swashbuckle or Springfox)?

Comment: The Swagger UI from the repo

Answer (score 0):

I just utilize tags

```
tags:
  - name: Unimplemented/Proposed
  description: Proposed endpoints that are not yet implemented
```

and then on the endpoint

```
paths:
  /myEndpointThatsNotReadyYet:
     get:
        tags:
          - Unimplemented/Proposed
```